# Django migrations: crashing in a data migration refering to an already removed model field

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

Creating test database, Django is raising this exception

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'xxx' into field. Choices are: ...
```

The failing migration is a custom one, moving data from (let's say) `ModelA` to `ModelB`:

```py
def forwards(apps, schema_editor):
    ...
    prev_list = ModelA.objects.all().values_list('xxx').distinct()
    for item in prev_list:
        ModelB(xxx=item).save()
```

My next movement has been checked `ModelA` which, ok expected, doesn't have a field called `XXX`

```
class ModelA(Model):
   # no field named xxx
```

Digging a little bit what happened here:

1. `ModelA` used to have a field named `xxx`
2. there is a migration trying to create `ModelB` rows reading from `ModelA.xxx`
3. `ModelA` doesn't have such field since there is a later migration removing that field, so I don't have the field declared in my model.

Why is failing the creation of the test database (from `python manage.py test`)? 
how can I fix this?

Comment: How do you get `ModalA` and `ModelB` classes in your migration file? You should be getting them from the `apps` parameter and not importing them from the source files

Comment: When Django start creating test db it introspects models and detects that there is no `xxx` field right now while migration is trying to use this field - I may guess this is what causing the error.

Comment: @ivissani that's it! I guess I can edit the bugged migration file and use `apps.get_model()` - it's importing the model as usual instead of using the historical version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't import `ModelA` directly, but import the historical version as below (see documentation on writing migrations [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/writing-migrations/)).

```
ModelA = apps.get_model('myapp', 'ModelA')
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#historical-models), you can edit an old migration if you run into this problem:

> ...historical model problems may not be immediately obvious. If you run into this kind of failure, it’s OK to edit the migration to use the historical models rather than direct imports and commit those changes.